# Type is not supported in a Windows App project

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, windows-store-apps

How do I reference a type from a XAML style or template? The WPF syntax does not work in my Windows Store project.

The IDE barks at me with "Type is not supported in a Windows App project".

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the following syntax:

```
<Style TargetType="xmlNamespacePrefix:MyControlClassName" >
    ...
```

That is, you do not need to use the {x:Type } syntax in Windows Store and Phone apps.

MSDN says:

> If you have used XAML for Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF), then
>   you might have used an x:Type markup extension to fill in any XAML
>   values that take a System.Type. The Windows Runtime XAML parser does
>   not support x:Type. Instead, you should refer to the type by name
>   without using any markup extension, and any necessary XAML-to-backing
>   type conversion is already handled by the built-in conversion behavior
>   in the XAML parser.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.style.targettype

Comment: I am not sure I understand... If I want a style BasedOn  a default style, say, of a ListViewItem. Do I just do BasedOn="ListViewItem"? Because that doesn't work.. :(

Comment: @ShaharPrish I'd suggest just posting a new question.